# Adaptive rotation axis when navigating

Tags: navigation

I have always been confused with the way to navigate around 3D objects.

I am learning Blender, and I am wondering how to make it understand when the rotation axis should change. Let me explain:

- If I click on the X, it centers my object, and moving my mouse from top to bottom rotates along the Y axis. Moving the mouse from left to right rotates along the Z axis.
- If I click on the Z though, I can still on rotate along the Y and Z axis, when in fact, I would want to rotate along the X and Y axis

Is there a way to make blender adapt the rotational axes depending on the current view?

Thanks.

Comment: For such questions, you should view blender documentation. If you have a mouse or a middle button if you're using your laptop, you can click and then move around holdind the button. You can also use Shift+Middle Mouse button to pan the view.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Orientation is everything in 3d and your question has many possible answers due to what your object has had done to it. Like, Cloning, Parenting, Applying scale, transformation, and rotation can affect how an object behaves. this video may help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ABayYXu7OfI